# Scoping resources per HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using this code in an MVC application to manage objects that should only have one instance per request.

```
/// <summary>
/// Manage all the resources that we want to scope to a single HTTP request.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class should not be directly referenced in many places.
/// In general, infrastructure code is OK whereas application code is not.
/// </remarks>
sealed class RequestScoped : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly object key = typeof(RequestScoped);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the RequestScoped instance for the given HttpContext.
    /// Creates and returns a new instance if it doesn't exist yet.
    /// This method is not thread-safe.
    /// The assumption is that there will only be one thread per request.
    /// </summary>
    public static RequestScoped GetOrCreate(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Items.Contains(key))
        {
            context.Items[key] = new RequestScoped();
            context.AddOnRequestCompleted(Cleanup);
        }
        return (RequestScoped)context.Items[key];
    }

    private static void Cleanup(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Items.Contains(key))
        {
            var scope = (RequestScoped)context.Items[key];
            scope.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private readonly Lazy<IDbConnection> connection;
    private readonly Lazy<SessionRepository> sessionRepo;

    private RequestScoped()
    {
        connection = new Lazy<IDbConnection>(() => Utilities.MakeOpenConnection());
        sessionRepo = new Lazy<SessionRepository>(() => new SessionRepository(connection));
    }

    public IDbConnection OpenConnection { get { return connection.Value; } }
    public SessionRepository SessionRepo { get { return sessionRepo.Value; } }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (connection.IsValueCreated)
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.Value.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Value.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // ignore
            }
            connection.Value.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage is like this:

```
protected IDbConnection OpenConnection
{
    get { return RequestScoped.GetOrCreate(HttpContext.Current).OpenConnection; }
}
```

(I am aware of DI containers but I have chosen not to use one in this application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it specific to the two properties you have currently? I think it would make sense to make it more generic, but I can't think of a good design to do that.

---

```
sealed class RequestScoped : IDisposable
```

Is it okay for users to call `Dispose()` by themselves? If not, don't make this type `IDisposable` and don't make `Dispose()` `public`.

---

```
private static readonly object key = typeof(RequestScoped);
```

Since other pieces of code have access to `typeof(RequestScoped)`, they could potentially read or overwrite the `RequestScoped` instance that's stored in the context by accident. To be on the safe side, I would use `new object()` here.

---

```
/// This method is not thread-safe.
```

I'm not sure you need to call this out here. Especially since this method is thread-safe, as long as different threads use different contexts.

---

```
public static RequestScoped GetOrCreate(System.Web.HttpContext context)
```

The fact that this method either gets existing object or creates a new one sounds like an implementation detail to me. I would probably call it just `Get()`.

Why are you repeating the namespace for `HttpContext` instead of using `using`?

---

```
public IDbConnection OpenConnection { get { return connection.Value; } }
```

Is "open" here supposed to be a verb or an adjective? If verb, then that's not appropriate for a property. If adjective, then it's I think it's not necessary.

---

```
public SessionRepository SessionRepo { get { return sessionRepo.Value; } }
```

I don't see any reason to shorten "repository" to "repo" here, `SessionRepository` is not that long.

---

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (connection.IsValueCreated)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection.Value.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Value.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignore
        }
        connection.Value.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Why are you not disposing `SessionRepository`? Is that not necessary?

Also, why are you trying to call `Close()` and then also call `Dispose()`? Isn't just `Dispose()` enough?